# Get all channels associated with a PubNub subscribe key

Tags: pubnub

Is it possible to get all the channels associated with a Pubnub subscribe key? 
All channels that were ever created using this key?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a list of all channels that are ***actively*** subscribed to using a Global Here Now call - http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/presence#gobal_here_now

There is no option to get a list of channels that were "created" in the past but are not active now. Here are a couple of alternatives that could work for you.

**Stream Controller (Channel Groups)**

With channel groups, you can manage subscriptions to channels centrally. By assigning a channel group to each user, you can list all channels (active or inactive) that were added to their channel group. PubNub maintains the subscription list for all channel groups and here's how you will retrieve them

http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/stream-controller#listing_channels_within_group

**Presence Callbacks**

PubNub allows you to specify a HTTP callback URL that is triggered when a channel becomes "active" or "inactive". This way, your server will be notified whenever a channel is "created" and you can persist that information to a database so you can query at a later time.